# Iphone Update to 15.1 Safari

Tags: css, iphone, safari

I recently updated to iphone 15.1. I opened the Safari browser and looked at my website. The 'send' button on all my forms has turned blue. It wasn't that way before. What's going on? How can I change this?

Answer (score -1):

You may take a look at what color does the button use with the safari's Developer Tools, and by connecting your iPhone.

As you did not provide your code, I guess your button may be using the color inherited from `html` or `body`. You may try to explicitly specify the color on the button. For example:

```css
.your-button-classname { 
    color: #your_color;
}
```